# click and hover function on same element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a small problem with mouse over/leave/click function.

It's working fine but after clicking the element it's losing the hover function.**I can't get the hover function once the element is clicked.**

```
$('.bg').click(function () {
    $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
    $('.bg').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');

}).hover(function () {    
    $(this).addClass('active');
}, function () {    
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

jsfiddle --

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/SVkBs/1/

Not sure where I am doing the mistake.Thanks.

Comment: So... what do you _expect_ to happen when you unbind the hover events on click?

Comment: I feel like my response is going to get downvoted because of how obvious it is... I must be missing something lol

Comment: Right so I have  tried by using bind again just after the click function ends. But I can't get the other box on hover effect.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra You haven't specified when you want the handlers bound again, or why you're unbinding in the first place... Are you after something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ykY2t/

Comment: @Jason the main problem is I can't use css here otherwise it's just simple the way it is.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use css, but this solution doesn't have any more css than your example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YtukK/. Does that work for you?

Comment: As I said I can't use the css hover funciton or I have to change the html which I don't want. I have a ul li (li has a background image). Inside the li there is a div having another small background image. Now on hover the li, that div which is containing the small bg image should change.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra Are you able to add an additional `.bg` class to the CSS? If so, I have a solution and will edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `:hover` CSS to the elements like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/SVkBs/2/

Comment: Don't worry, it's obvious.

Comment: Thanks Agony. The problem is I can't use any css here. That's the limitation.Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

What [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) does is to bind a `mouseenter` and a `mouseleave` handler. What [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) does is to remove those handlers from firing.

So your code is doing exactly what you told it to; when you click, it disables your hover handling.

Comment: I know. Now what I need is to tell click function to bind the hover function again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.bg').click(function () {
    /* remove that following line  */
    $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");  /* <-- this will UNBIND the 'hover' */
    /* did you remove that previous line ? */
    $('.bg').removeClass('active'); /* <-- this will remove 'active' from .bg */
    $(this).addClass('active');  /* <-- this will add 'active' on this(.bg) */
}).hover(function () {    /* <-- this will try to addClass 'active' on hover .. */
    $(this).addClass('active');
}, function () {    /* <-- this will try to removeClass on the otherHand (callback) */
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

ps. This function is working all right, you just didn't know what it is supposed to do (unbinding hover events).

---

**do it this way (toggling a class on hover)**

```
$('.bg').hover(
       function(){ $(this).addClass('active') },
       function(){ $(this).removeClass('active') }
)
```

Comment: Probably you haven't gone through my question thoroughly.

Comment: Well, what is your question then ? You want the hover event back ? You want to be able to hover after you 'clicK' your element.bg ? Just NOT unbind the mouseenter-mouseleave.